# How to set multiple Jquery-UI resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use Jquery-UI to resize different `div` but they have different "type" with different parameters (minWidth, minHeight, aspectratio ...). This code works but maybe the final code will have 20 "type".

How could I optimize this code ?

```
$(".child").resizable({
    containment: "parent",
    resize: function( event,ui ){
        if(ui.element.attr('data-type')=="type-b"){
            // specific code to type-b
        }
        if($(this).attr('data-type')=="type-c"){
            // specific code to type-c
        }
    },
    stop: function (event,ui) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: ui.element.attr('id')},
            success: function (child_id) {
                var parent_id = $('#main').attr('id'),
                    full_id =(parent_id+"_"+child_id),
                    child_width = ui.size.width,
                    child_height = ui.size.height,
                    t=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(full_id));

                t.width=child_width;t.height=child_height;
                sessionStorage.setItem(full_id,JSON.stringify(t));
            }
        });
        if(ui.element.attr('data-type')=="type-a"){
            // specific code to type-a
        }
        if($(this).attr('data-type')=="type-b"){
            // specific code to type-b
        }
    }
});

$(".child.type-a").resizable({
    minWidth: 200,
    minHeight: 50,
    handles : "e,w"
}),$(".child.type-b").resizable({
    minWidth: 160,
    minHeight: 110,
    handles : "e,w"
}),$(".child.type-c").resizable({
    minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 185,
    aspectRatio: 1.618/1
});
```

Comment: BTW as far as I know, you're destroying the common `$(".child").resizable` when you do `$(".child.type-a").resizable({` etc later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each is unique, then you won't get too far away from what you have. One option would be to store all the variables in an object and iterate each to set the options. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hovqphko/

```
$(function() {
  var resOptions = {
    "type-a": {
      minWidth: 200,
      minHeight: 50,
      handles: "e,w"
    },
    "type-b": {
      minWidth: 160,
      minHeight: 110,
      handles: "e,w"
    },
    "type-c": {
      minWidth: 300,
      minHeight: 185,
      aspectRatio: 1.618 / 1
    }
  };

  $(".child").resizable({
    containment: "parent"
  });

  $.each(resOptions, function(k, v) {
    console.log("Setting", k, "to", v);
    $("." + k).resizable("option", v);
  });
});
```